# Error ERROR (undefined_table) in a full text search with Ecto and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying my implement a very basic full text search in my Phoenix application using Ecto and PostgreSQL. Based on one example and PostgreSQL docs I have in my controller:

```
def search(conn, %{"q" => para}) do
    search = User |> User.search(para) |> Repo.all
    render(conn, "search.html", search: search)
  end
```

and in my "model" file (along with the definition of the `User` fields):

```
def search(query, search_term) do
    (from u in query,
    where: fragment("to_tsvector(u.name) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", ^search_term),
    order_by: fragment("ts_rank(to_tsvector(u.name), plainto_tsquery(?)) DESC", ^search_term))
  end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR (undefined_table): missing FROM-clause entry for table "u"
```

Isn't `from u in query`, enough (`name` is one of `User` fields)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `u.name` like that. `u` is just a name that exists in Elixir when compiling the query to SQL. It gets renamed while it is compiled. You need to add another `?` to `fragment` and pass `u.name` for that:

```
def search(query, search_term) do
  from u in query,
    where: fragment("to_tsvector(?) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", u.name, ^search_term),
    order_by: fragment("ts_rank(to_tsvector(?), plainto_tsquery(?)) DESC", u.name, ^search_term)
end
```

Comment: It's working but now when trying to access `<%=@search%>` in my template I get another error because I'm getting all the data from the model: `lists in Phoenix.HTML and templates may only contain integers representing bytes, binaries or other lists, got invalid entry: %MyProj.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">, contacts: "Tlm: 22222222", details: nil, facebook: nil, id: 16, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-03 13:55:30>, name: "blabla",  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-03 13:55:30>, web_page: nil}`. I've tried to use dot notation without success...

Comment: `@search` is a list. What exactly do you want to print from the list? You can use something like `for`: `<%= for user <- @search do %> <%= user.name %> <% end %>`.

Comment: Right! I'm just too upset to think straight! First time with SQL and feeling like I'll never get it :) I'm going to open a few more focused questions as I get stuck. Thanks Dogbert!